# Using NumPy reduceat to calculate group based averages

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dummies = np.array(pd.get_dummies(list('abdccadab'))) #categorical IV
groupIDs = np.array([10,10,10,10,20,20,30,30,30]) #groups(/strata)
_,idx,tags = np.unique(groupIDs, return_index=1, return_inverse=1)
```

I know we can do sums, multiplications etc per group, per column, eg.

```
np.multiply.reduceat(dummies,idx)[tags]
```

but is there a way to calculate the means of these bins?

`np.mean.reduceat` and `np.average.reduceat` don't work because

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'reduceat'
```

Comment: Only `ufunc` have `reduceat`.  `mean` and `average` are not this type of function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're trying to do this using pure numpy (as opposed to doing a pandas groupby)?

Comment: No specific reason other than I am less familiar with pandas than numpy and was not even aware that it could be done in pandas as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.add.reduceat` to get per column summations of data array `dummies` based on the interval shifts `idx` and then divide by the interval lengths computed with `np.bincount` -

```
np.add.reduceat(dummies, idx, axis=0)/np.bincount(tags)[:,None]
```

Another way to compute the interval lengths would be with directly using `idx` -

```
np.diff(np.r_[idx,dummies.shape[0]])
```

Again, we can avoid the usage of `np.unique` to get `idx`, like so -

```
idx = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(groupIDs[1:] > groupIDs[:-1])+1]
```

Comment: Thanks again! And how would we put the output of `np.add.reduceat(dummies, idx, axis=0)/np.bincount(tags)[:,None]` to the same dimensions as the dummies? -i.e. what we would achieve in `np.multiply.reduceat(dummies,idx)` with te addition of `[tags]` at the end.

Comment: @Tony I am not clear on the query about `tags`. I have used `tags` here with `np.bincount` to get the count of each interval and thus compute averages. Not sure how you plan to use it with `np.multiply.reduceat`. Could you elaborate or rephrase?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. When calling any of the `sum`, `multiply` etc on each own, as in the example in the original post, that is, not divided by `np.bincount` to get the mean, then the returned array is of the same shape as our original one. So my current question is how to reshape the output of `np.add.reduceat(dummies, idx, axis=0)/np.bincount(tags)[:,None]` to have the same dimensions as the original array. In this example, the first 4 elements of first row would be 0.25, the two following would be 0.5 etc. I am editing my question with the desired output.

Comment: @Tony IIUC simply index with `tags` : `out[tags]`, where `out` is the output from `np.add.reduceat(dummies, idx, axis=0)/np.bincount(tags)[:,None]`. Does that help?

Comment: absolutely sir.

Answer (score 3):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) offers this type of functionality as a single-line statement:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_groups, means = npi.group_by(groupIDs).mean(dummies)
```

For this case (already sorted keys) it offers linear and vectorized performance; although with more extra overhead than the specialized solution posted by Divakar, which already has this assumption baked-in. But depending on how you weight maintainability, self-documentability and generality, this could be a preferred alternative.